# alert blocks cross window communication in IE

Tags: javascript

I do have implemented a cross window communication in javascript between a parent-window and an iframe-window.

Everything works perfectly, but as soon as an alert-window gets opened on the parent-window, within a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('test'); }, 100);
```

the communication from the iframe-window to the parent-window is blocked until I do close the alert-window.

If the alert gets opened not within a timeout, not the communication between the iframe and the window gets blocked, but only the alert itself, what would be fine for me.

Has somebody made the same experience and how could this be solved ?

My **code** is very simple:

- **window (parent)**

  ```
  window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessageFromIFrameFunc);
  iframe.postMessage( textJson, '*');
  ```
- **iframe**

  ```
  window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessageFromParentFunc);
  window.parent.postMessage( textJson, '*');
  ```

Is there a solution to get this issue solved ?

What is the main difference between alert and alert within a timeout and why does the timeout alert block the whole cross window communication ?

Comment: Simple, don't use `alert`, it not only has *blocking* problems like what you're experiencing, it's also very user-unfriendly. Use a proper modal instead

Comment: Thanks, but it is not really an option, because I do implement something in a legacy system, which I cannot touch.

What I could verify that the alert is only a problem, if the alert gets opened within the event-listener of the parent-window. 
It seems that the open alert blocks any further events from being processed.